# Delete rows from MySQL using JSF

Tags: mysql, jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to delete row from the MySQL table, here is my admin.xhtml:

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{userController.items}"
                 var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2"
                 cellspacing="0" rules="all"
                 style="border:solid 1px">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserTitle_iduser}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.iduser}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserTitle_username}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.username}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:commandLink action="#{userController.destroyUser(item.iduser)}"
                           value="#{bundle.ListUserDestroyLink}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And then in my `userController` I have a method `destroyUser`.

```java
public String destroyUser(int iduser) {

    try {
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();
        String sql = "DELETE FROM projekt2.user WHERE iduser =" + iduser;
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return "admin";
}
```

I know that writing SQL queries like this is not nice, anyway after clicking the destroy link nothing happens unless I click to destroy the user that I'm currently logged on, then it is deleted from the table. I can't delete any other user. But since `#{item.iduser}` gets the right value, then `#{userController.destroyUser(item.iduser)}` should get the right value as well right?

@edit

Okay I think I know what the problem is. I've got another table with a foreign key on my user table (each advertisement added has its userId as a foreign key) and that is why it prevented me from deleting users that have at least 1 advertisement added (admin didn't have any so i was able to delete him). Can u tell me where do I change so it will work, somewhere in the database or maybe in my entities? I'm using MySQL Workbench

Comment: Put this statement `System.out.println("iduser : " + iduser);` in the beginning of the `destroyUser()` method to see, if a correct value corresponding to a user is supplied or not on each click of `<h:commandLink>`.

Comment: I checked with debugger, `iduser` values are correct, it still works only for the user i'm logged in, others are left untouched

Comment: You are already using a `PreparedStatement` though you are concatenating field values in the said SQL statement. Why don't you just replace it with a placeholder `?` in conjunction with an appropriate `ps.setXxx(1, iduser)` method depending upon the type of `iduser`? Or if you are currently not interested in using a `PreparedStatement` then, just simply replace it by `Statement` instead.

Comment: I changed it to `Statement`

Comment: What then? You said, "*I click to destroy the user that I'm currently logged on, then it is deleted from the table*". Here you are implying that the currently logged in user (i.e you yourself as the system  administrator gets deleted, when the given `<h:commandLink>` is pressed). How would you be able to delete other users afterwards. Would you even be able to login afterwards, if the system administrator himself/herself was deleted?

Comment: My problem is that the only "destroy" link that works is the one for the admin (and that's the user that I'm logged in). But even before deleting admin i cant delete other users, although the sql seems to be ok. When i delete admin i just create a new one in database and try again, but it's the same every time

Comment: Are you enough sure that the value (i.e `iduser`) supplied by the parameterized action method on each click of the mentioned `<h:commandLink>` exactly matches the corresponding primary key value in the table based on which the selected user is to be deleted? (this is the only requirement to delete a row from the database unless otherwise there are some bugs in your own code. If it happens then, the target row should be deleted for sure). Are there other users too in the database table or you are accidently having only one user (representing you yourself) and hereby you see what you mentioned?

Comment: Okay I think I know what the problem is. I've got another table with a foreign key on my user table (each advertisement added has its userId as a foreign key) and that is why it prevented me from deleting users that have at least 1 advertisement. Can u tell me where do I change so it will work, somewhere in the database or maybe in my entities?

Comment: "*entities*"? You are currently showing plain JDBC. Therefore, there is no such things as "*entities*". The `Logger` in the `catch` block should have reported an appropriate exception expressing something like, "*Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails*". Do you receive this message (please do not merely swallow exceptions)? (It is fully requirement dependent. If you need to delete children corresponding to a parent, when a parent is deleted then, you need to enforce cascade delete by altering the table).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,  I've got another table with a foreign key on my user table (each advertisement added has its userId as a foreign key) and that is why it prevented me from deleting users that have at least 1 advertisement added. So I had to set "On Delete" Option to "Cascade" (or maybe u can set different value) in foreign key options in MySQL Workbench.

Thanks Tiny for your answers, my comments might have been a bit misleading